# Agent taking different paths?

Tags: unity, navmesh

I don't know of this is possible or not. I was following [Unity - The NavMesh Agent tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation/navmesh-agent?playlist=17105).
What I'm thinking on how to make the agent take's different path ? example, if i have two agents, how to make both of them taking different paths ?

Comment: If the start point and destination point are the same, they will compute the same shorter path. You have to add an extra intermediate point to make them take different paths.

Comment: Could you please give me an example ?

Comment: It's not really possible, supposing your path is composed of 3 points (start, intermediate and final point), you just have to determine the position of the intermediate so that it is on the 1st path or the other.